# Selecting values from objects in document nested array in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Imagine we have a such collection (example taken from  https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo)

```
{
    "_id" : "19015",
    "description" : "Snacks, granola bars, hard, plain",
    "servings" : [ 
        {
            "amount" : 1,
            "description" : "bar",
            "weightInGrams" : 21
        }, 
        {
            "amount" : 1,
            "description" : "bar (1 oz)",
            "weightInGrams" : 28
        }, 
        {
            "amount" : 1,
            "description" : "bar",
            "weightInGrams" : 25
        }
    ]
}
```

How i can query CosmosDB in SQL api to get results such like this?

```
{
    "_id" : "19015",
    "servings" : [ 
        {
            "description" : "bar"
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "bar (1 oz)"
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

at MongoDB i would use such query

```
db.getCollection('food').find({id: '19015'}, {'servings.description' : 1})
```

Tried multiple scenarious with joins etc

```
SELECT 
    food.id,
    food.servings.description
FROM food
WHERE food.id = "19015"
```

or

```
SELECT 
    food.id,
    [{
        description: food.servings[0].description
    }] AS servings
FROM food
WHERE food.id = "19015"
```

- instead of `[0]` i tried `[]` or `[$]` but doesn't works

Does somebody has idea how in simply way i can resolve this issue?

Comment: I believe you have exact answer, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 11):

You could use the ARRAY(subquery) expression to achieve this. Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    food.id,
    ARRAY(SELECT serving.description FROM serving IN food.servings) AS servings
FROM food
WHERE food.id = "19015"
```

Comment: So, there are subqueries now in CosmosDB. Any pointers regarding documentation?

Comment: Yes, Cosmos DB recently added support for subqueries. We're currently working on publishing the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

By executing this query:

```
select food.id, servings.description
from food join servings in food.servings
```

you would at least get the following result:

```
{"id":19015, "description":"bar"}
{"id":19015, "description":"bar (1 oz)"}
{"id":19015, "description":"bar"}
```

Not 100% what you were expecting, but maybe something you can work with!